# Rstudio filename completion in rmarkdown .rmd files

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

In Rstudio version (1.0.143).

I am using an Rstudio package project and using Rmarkdown in it. All the code files are in the ./R folder. All the data files are in the ./Data folder. The default `getwd()` is the parent folder ./ (that contains ./R and ./Data).

I use the file completion tool in RStudio and I think it's very useful. But in an .Rmd file, it does not work as expected. For example, here are the two situations:

- In a .R file, contained in ./R folder. I open the brackets and the
  completion works as one would expect, relative to the `getwd()`
  folder, ie the parent. So a file "hello.R" in ./R would complete as
  "./R/hello.R"
- In an .Rmd file, also contained in ./R folder. I start an R chunk. I
  open the brackets and the completion does not give me the "./R"
  folder, and even though `getwd()` gives the parent "./", the
  completion for the file "hello.R" in ./R gives "hello.R".

Is this a known bug or a feature?

```
> sessionInfo() 
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_0.12.12        compiler_3.4.1      RColorBrewer_1.1-2  plyr_1.8.4          base64enc_0.1-3     tools_3.4.1         rpart_4.1-11         [8] digest_0.6.12       evaluate_0.10.1     tibble_1.3.4        gtable_0.2.0        htmlTable_1.9       checkmate_1.8.3     lattice_0.20-35     [15] rlang_0.1.2         Matrix_1.2-11       gridExtra_2.2.1     stringr_1.2.0       cluster_2.0.6       knitr_1.17 htmlwidgets_0.9     [22] grid_3.4.1          nnet_7.3-12         data.table_1.10.4   survival_2.41-3     foreign_0.8-69      pacman_0.4.6        latticeExtra_0.6-28 [29] Formula_1.2-2       ggplot2_2.2.1       magrittr_1.5        Hmisc_4.0-3         scales_0.5.0        backports_1.1.0     htmltools_0.3.6     [36] splines_3.4.1       colorspace_1.3-2    stringi_1.1.5       acepack_1.4.1       lazyeval_0.2.0      munsell_0.4.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Rmd files wd is the Rmd file's path. Although you can change that to be the project directory (options->rmarkdown->evaluate chunks in directory: project), it seems that the path autocomplete is still in the Rmd path, as you said.
What I am doing is finding the right path with the autocomplete in the terminal, and then paste it to the Rmd file... Not perfect but it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The RStudio filename completion is based on the *current working directory*, i.e. `getwd()` as you yourself has identified.

When knitting a Rmd file, the directory containing the Rmd file is used as working directory. So when your Rmd file is found in `./R`, this becomes your working directory.

The easiest solution is for you to change working directory to `./R` while developing your Rmd file.

There are some options for you to investigate. RStudio uses `render` from the rmarkdown package. See e.g. `?rmarkdown::render`; look at `knit_root_dir`.
This is also available for your knitr document as

```
knit::opts_knit$set(root.dir='../')
```

***Edit:*** It would seem that RStudio (v. 1.0.136) is clever enough to recognise that the knitr document will be knitted based from its directory, and thus uses auto completion from *that* directory, not `getwd()`.

Comment: That s what I thought but it's not correct in my case. In a package project in Rstudio, the main directory containing the files is "./R" while the `getwd()` folder, is "./".

If the .Rmd is in "./R", when I run the chunk the `getwd()` folder, is "./". Also, when i knit it, the `getwd()` folder, is "./" too!
It's just the completion that is messed up. For every autocomplete file name, I have to add "./R" in order for the file to either knit or run all chunks.

I think what you are saying may have been true before but not anymore my Rstudio version (1.0.143) - which is good.

Comment: In a package project, `getwd()` can still be anything. RStudio *defaults* to the package-root. From my experience, RStudio bases file completion in `getwd()` for R-files, but for Rmd files, it bases it in the directory of the Rmd file, regardless of working directory.

Comment: I pressed enter too quickly, see edit. 
Let me try moving my Rmd file to one of those folders. Maybe then I won't have a problem.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to solve this problem? I have an Rmd document that is in ./code, but have it's wd set to the root directory (.) via a line in the opening chunk:

    knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "../") 

However, when tabbing out to find files while writing in the Rmd document it still insists on starting in the ./code directory even though the console's working directory is set to the root directory. It would be nice to set this somehow in the RStudio IDE settings.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty witt my previous comment. "../" does mean parent directory.